# How to use Windows C++ AttatchConsole with Cygwin terminals

Tags: c++, windows, command-line-interface, cygwin

I have a c++ windows application that runs via a GUI. I made a CLI for it to automate some things and this works fine if I use

```
AllocConsole();
```

or even

```
AttachConsole(PID);
```

as long as it is attaching to a windows CMD terminal.

I want to attach to a Cygwin terminal so I can use Expect to automate some things, but attach console always fails here and results in errors when trying to write to it.

Does anyone know how to make a windows application attach to a Cygwin terminal like this?

Answer (score 0):

Not all cygwin terminals use the windows console. If you are not using a windows console then AttachConsole simply will not help you.

In particular a mintty.exe terminal will not work with AttachConsole because it is not a windows console.

Comment: Ok, so how do I attatch to a mintty console in windows then?

Comment: Have you tried using `stdin` and `stdout` (or the C++ equivalent) in your CLI program?